# DNS Fails to simple query test

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008, query

I seem to have a real odd problem that seems to escape me. I have two servers - both of which are ad controllers. My Problem Child is Windows 2008 R2, My other is a Windows 2012R2 that runs no problem.

If I go into the monitor section of DNS and run both the Simple Query and Recursive. The Simple will Fail, and the Recursive will pass. These same test work fine on the Windows 2k12 system.

I have also tried doing an NSLOOKUP ans well as flushing the dns. Reboots make no difference. Nothing is logged and turning on debugging yields no leads. Additionally, I have turned of the Windows Firewall, McAfee AV and Malware Bytes.

I have all windows updates though July 2019 installed. DNS on this system just does not want to answer any queries. Since the second server is responding, the problem is not catastrophic, however if the second server is rebooted -- that is it.

I am possibly considering rebuilding the system at this point...

Answer (score 0):

Check the root hints tab, is it populated?

A simple query will cause the dns server to look into its own cache for an answer to your query, if it doesn't have an answer it will refer you to one of the root hint servers.

In the case of a recursive query it will ask the forwarders on your behalf.

Check root hints.

Comment: The DNS forwarders are pointed to Google and Level 3 communications.  Root Hints are updated to current and match the working server.  

In the mean time, still looking to fix...maybe remove and re-install DNS......not sure if its possible.  Planning to move  FSMOs this weekend.

Comment: You can't remove DNS without demoting the machine. Transferring FSMO is simple and only takes a couple minutes. You might want to try that, (transfer FSMO, demote, reboot, promote). I'd like to hear if it gets results for you.

Comment: One other thought before you do all of that, have you run dcdiag? And did it pass all tests? Well, obviously not all of the tests, but did it fail any others?